# Find all string variables in javascript files

Tags: javascript, regex, string, translation

i am facing the problem that i have to translate a larger html and javascript project into several languages. The html content was no problem, but the numerous javascript files are problematic, since i was a bit lazy during the development process. For instance, if i needed a message text, i just added it in the concerning position.

My approach now is, that i am using a build-in file search (Eclipse) for every occurrence of `"` and `'`, which i am getting line-wise. This would be extremely time consuming and errors are unavoidable.

Here are some examples that occur in the files:

```
var d = "Datum: " + d.getDate()+"."+(d.getMonth()+1)+"."+d.getFullYear();

showYesNoDialog("heading text","Are you sure?",function(){};
```

Sometimes i am mixing `"` and `'`, sometimes a string goes over several lines:

```
var list="";
list+='<li data-role="list-divider">';
list+='Text To Translate';
list+='</li>';
```

Things i don't want to get, are jquery selectors, e.g.:

```
$("input[name^=checkbox]").each(function () {};
```

Do you see any time saving method to get all of the strings that i would like to translate?
Regex? A java interpreter? Grep?

I know, that is a bit unusual question.
So any suggestion would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to use some kind of the lexical scanner that converts the code into the tokens and then walk over the list of tokens (or syntax tree). There is a number of such tools (I even created one of them myself - here you can find some of the examples https://github.com/AlexAtNet/spelljs/blob/master/test/scan.js).

With it you can scan the JS file and just iterate over the tokens:

```
var scan = require('./..../scan.js');

scan(text).forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.str) {
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: This was a great hint. Thank you very much!
There is also a good solution under https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=11538&lngWId=3

This does exactly what i need.